# C++ implementation of Trie with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, trie

This question is about a solution I am attempting to leetcode 208. Implement Trie (Prefix Tree). https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-trie-prefix-tree

I have a TrieNode, and because I need to "store an incomplete type" of TrieNode inside the unordered_map within itself I need to use some kind of pointer. IE: the following is not possible:

```
class TrieNode{
public:
    std::unordered_map<char, TrieNode> childTrie;  //ERROR: incomplete type
    bool lastCharacter = false;
};
```

As such I wanted to use a unique_ptr instead of a raw pointer here, as a chance to practice using unique_ptr's/C++ smart pointers.

However I have compiler error in my implementation and I am not sure what the error is. I have copied the code and the full error below.

I think that the error is because I am copying the unique_ptr somewhere, but I do not understand where this is happening and would appreciate some help tracking that down - or perhaps I totally do not understand what the error is at all! Thanks

```
class TrieNode{
public:
    std::unordered_map<char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode>> childTrie; 
    bool lastCharacter = false;
};

class Trie {
public:
    
    void insert(string word) {
        
        TrieNode currentNode = root;
        
        for (auto c : word)
        {
            if (currentNode.childTrie.find(c) == currentNode.childTrie.end())
            {
                currentNode.childTrie.insert(std::make_pair(c, std::make_unique<TrieNode>()));
            }
            currentNode = *(currentNode.childTrie[c].get());   
            
        }
        currentNode.lastCharacter = true; 
    }
    
    bool search(string word) {

        TrieNode currentNode = root;
    
        for (auto c : word)
        {
            if (currentNode.childTrie.find(c) == currentNode.childTrie.end())
            {
                return false;
            }
            currentNode = *currentNode.childTrie[c].get();
        }
        
        return currentNode.lastCharacter;
    }
    
    bool startsWith(string prefix) {
        
        TrieNode currentNode = root;
    
        for (auto c : prefix)
        {
            if (currentNode.childTrie.find(c) == currentNode.childTrie.end())
            {
                return false;
            }
            currentNode = *currentNode.childTrie[c].get();
        }
        
        return true;
 
    }
                                                  
    TrieNode root;
    
};

/**
 * Your Trie object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * Trie* obj = new Trie();
 * obj->insert(word);
 * bool param_2 = obj->search(word);
 * bool param_3 = obj->startsWith(prefix);
 */
```

```
In file included from prog_joined.cpp:1:
In file included from ./precompiled/headers.h:25:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ccomplex:39:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/complex:45:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/sstream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/istream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ios:42:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/string:41:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:46:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++allocator.h:33:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:146:8: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>'
                            _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
                            ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/alloc_traits.h:483:24: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'construct<std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>, const std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>> &>' requested here
        noexcept(noexcept(__a.construct(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
                              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2086:27: note: in instantiation of exception specification for 'construct<std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>, const std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>> &>' requested here
            __node_alloc_traits::construct(_M_node_allocator(),
                                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:1243:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>, false>>>::_M_allocate_node<const std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>> &>' requested here
                { return this->_M_allocate_node(__n->_M_v()); });
                               ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:181:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::_Hashtable<char, std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<char>, std::hash<char>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true>>::_Hashtable' requested here
      unordered_map(const unordered_map&) = default;
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note: explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted here
      constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:215:11: note: copy constructor of 'pair<const char, std::unique_ptr<TrieNode, std::default_delete<TrieNode>>>' is implicitly deleted because field 'second' has a deleted copy constructor
      _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:414:7: note: 'unique_ptr' has been explicitly marked deleted here
      unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
      ^
```

Comment: Much smaller [mcve] - https://godbolt.org/z/Gv36GWGr8

Comment: Thank you Richard. I think a better example might be this: https://godbolt.org/z/qvf1PTf41

That is because I am not "explicitly" copying anywhere, I think that either make_pair or insert is doing an implicit copy, but cannot work it out or how to std::move instead. Note I think my above example might have an unrelated bug, not sure how to get a minimal reproducible example for the exact problem.

EDIT: https://godbolt.org/z/M7MM8Y9b7

I was not using make_pair, sorry! However this examples seems to work - so I am still quite lost :)

Comment: The copy is here `TrieNode currentNode = root;` (copy initialisation) in the original example. I made the example by commenting out every thing else.

Comment: You may use `emplace(c, std::make_unique<TrieNode>())` instead of insert.